# passwd command not changing the current user password

Tags: linux, users, passwd

I have tried with command:
$ passwd

It is asking new password and give success message but when I try to login with new password after restart the system. It work with old password. New password not changed! Any idea...

Comment: Are you sure you are typing in `passwd`? Because if you are using `sudo passwd` you are changing the root user password.

Comment: What [kemotep said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554426/passwd-command-not-changing-the-current-user-password#comment1029656_554426). If it's not asking you to confirm your _existing_ password (which you don't mention anything about), we will have to assume that you are indeed using `sudo passwd`, which will change the root user's password (without having to confirm the old password), not the password of the current user.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I changed passwords successfully, but a new password for didn't work for logging in or using `sudo`.

Turned out I had two `passwd` tools, for whatever reason.
One at `/usr/local/bin/passwd` and another at `/usr/bin/passwd`. Using the latter solved the issue.

You can run `type -a passwd` to see it.

Comment: I had two `passwd` tools as well. What worked for me was to log in as `root` and then run `passwd <target username>` to set the new password for the target user. Running `passwd` logged as the non-root target user didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `sudo`? If so, you might have changed your root password, not your user password.

To change your root password:

```
sudo passwd
```

To change your user password:

```
sudo passwd username
```

**EDIT**: A reviewer suggested that changing the user password should be simply:

```
passwd
```

However, this didn't work on the system I was using.

Comment: "_this didn't work_" - it certainly should work: users should not require system administrative privileges to change their own password. What happened (or didn't happen) when you tried `passwd`? Any error messages?

Comment: Sorry, I can't recall the details of the issue, or even on which system it occurred. Note that there is a comment on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/712033) with the same issue.

Comment: Daviewales, really the same issue, or just the same symptom?

Comment: Hard to say if it's the same issue, but certainly the same symptom and resolution.

Answer (score -1):

Try this it will work

//Delete the password for user
**`sudo passwd -d <user>`**

//Update new password
**`sudo passwd <user>`**

Comment: Why would you need to delete the password first?

Comment: How is this materially different from [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/728696/100397) that also suggested `sudo passwd {user}`?

Comment: Dangerous choice; issue very likely due to permissions.